# servicestack 4.5.14 & .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, servicestack, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I was excited to read that the latest release version of ServiceStack (4.5.14) supports .Net Core 2.0 (see [release notes](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.14)).  I tried adding ServiceStack 4.5.14 to my application targeting .Net Core 2.0.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="4.5.14" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="..\Local.Service\Local.Service.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I build the project, I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseServiceStack' and no extension method 'UseServiceStack' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Startup ...\Startup\Startup.cs  24  Active
```

And warnings for each of the ServiceStack packages like this one:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'ServiceStack 4.5.14' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. Local.Service   ...\Local.Service\Local.Service.csproj  1
```

The release notes to which I referred above reference example applications provided by the ServiceStack team.  However, all of the examples that support .Net Core 2.0 are also using ServiceStack 5.0 and not 4.5.14.

I added ServiceStack 5.0 to my project, and it does work nicely with .Net Core 2.0.  I would prefer to use a release version of the package, though, if possible.

Does v4.5.14 really support .Net Core 2.0?  If so, how?

Comment: As mentioned in @Justin's answer the [.NET Core builds of ServiceStack have a .Core prefix](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-servicestack-packages) in v4.5.x on NuGet, or you can use `ServiceStack` packages if you use the [latest ServiceStack v5 pre-release packages on MyGet](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ServiceStack.*.Core` packages rather than the `4.5.14` packages.

If you read further through the release notes, you'll see that .NET Core packages still aren't merged into the regular release packages. That's planned for v5:

> Merging the .NET Core packages into main packages where they’ll share
>   the same version and release cadence

The .NET Core 2.0 starter app is also deceptive as it references ServiceStack's MyGet feed and includes version 5 rather than 4.5.14.